# How to read yaml file from typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-eslint

I have tried to write a small piece of code in typescript to read yaml file but unfortunately it is not working.

```js
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises';
import { load } from 'js-yaml';

const filepath = 'src/commands/hello/test.yml';

const yaml = load(await readFile(filepath, "utf8")) as string;
const phrases = yaml.trainingPhrases;

console.log(phrases);
```

My yaml file

```yaml
---
trainingPhrases:
- help me
- what to do
- how to play
- help
```

Comment: What does _"it is not working"_ mean here? What happens? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I am getting this error:

PS C:\Users\amitpurushott.ranga\test> bin/run hello:test
(node:16816) ReferenceError Plugin: test: await is not defined

Comment: try to use [yamljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yamljs) package and let me know if it is working

Comment: yamljs package can be used in javascript. I am working on typescript. please provide me solution on typescript to read yaml file. thanks. :)

Comment: Your error message has nothing to do with js-yaml. Something is off with your node/typescript setup: it complains about await, try using readFileSync or something like that.